# EC2 instance can't connect to itself within a VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I'm struggling to get an EC2 just to connect to itself in a VPC (using inbound rules in its security group). That should be the *simplest* network topology I could come up with to test things out. Am I missing something when it comes to Private IPs? (are they special?), I thought Private IP's would only be visible from within a VPC, and this EC2 instance *is* within a VPC, and I'm not crossing any VPC boundaries either (since it's trying to connect to itself).

[image]

Comment: It must be something else that's happening. Curling your own private IP from inside instance is not affected by SGs or any VPCs. Maybe you have some internal firewall setup or elastic search is doing something that blocks. Can you install apache2 and curl that? `sudo apt install apache2; sudo systemctl start apache2; curl <private ip>`

Comment: What `network.x` settings (e.g. network.host) do you have in elasticsearch.yml?

Comment: installing apache & starting it works. I can curl my private IP (port 80), so maybe this is a firewall thing that only allows port 80 by default on ubuntu? Also, my elasticserach.yml is completely commented out (all defaults), so unless defaults don't allow IP addresses? (will experiment a bit!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, turns out it was an elasticsearch default / missing config!

the answer was to set the following in my `elasticsearch.yml`:

```
network.host: 127.0.0.1
http.port: 9200
http.host: 0.0.0.0
```

That seemed to fix it!

thanks to both @jarmod and @Marcin to help point me in the right direction! :D